# How do you change a cell based on a combobox value

Tags: excel

I have a sheet (sheet A) with an activeX combobox, this combobox is filled with dates from another sheet (sheet B) on the format "dd/mm/yyyy" in text.

Now what i want is that when i select some date in the combobox on sheet A, i get the same date in another cell but 2 years add to it. So if i select "01/01/2018" i get "01/01/2020". Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Range("A2") = DateAdd("yyyy", 2, Me.ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

Code goes in code pane of sheet containing the activex object. Change `A2` to the target output cell and `ComboBox1` to the appropriate combobox.

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you!
EDIT: would you happen to know how i change the date format in the output cell to dd/mm/yyyy? its for use in EU :)